# Aligning text in title between pictures

Tags: vertical-alignment, titles

I need help with aligning text in my simple custom title page. I wish to have title text and some additional text below centered horizontally between two logos. It would be nice if the logos would be center vertically also.

```
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

    % Upper part of the page. The '~' is needed because \\
    % only works if a paragraph has started.
        \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{./logo_pg}~%\\[1cm]
        \textsc{\LARGE University Name}
        \textsc{Faculty}
        \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{./logo_eti}
        \\[1.5cm]

    % Title
    \HRule \\[0.4cm]
    { \huge \bfseries Project's Name \\[0.4cm] }

    \HRule \\[1.5cm]

    \Large
    Author1 \\
    Author2

    \vfill

    % Bottom of the page
    {\large \today}

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

Oh and the HRule is defined in the main .tex file

```
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

\noindent%
\begin{minipage}{.15\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{fig-logo}
\end{minipage}
\hfil
\begin{minipage}{.68\linewidth}\centering
\textsc{\LARGE University Name} \\
\textsc{Faculty}
\end{minipage}
\hfil
\begin{minipage}{.15\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{fig-logo}
\end{minipage}

\vfill

\begin{center}
    \HRule \\[0.4cm]
    { \huge \bfseries Project's Name \\[0.4cm] }

    \HRule \\[1.5cm]

    \Large
    Author1 \\
    Author2

    \vfill

    {\large \today}

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need the command `raisebox`

```
\documentclass[titlepage,demo]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

    % Upper part of the page. The '~' is needed because \\
    % only works if a paragraph has started.
        \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{./logo_pg}}
        \begin{tabular}[c]{c}
           \textsc{\LARGE University Name} \\
            \textsc{Faculty}
        \end{tabular}
        \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{./logo_eti}}
        \\[1.5cm]

    % Title
    \HRule \\[0.4cm]
    { \huge \bfseries Project's Name \\[0.4cm] }

    \HRule \\[1.5cm]

    \Large
    Author1 \\
    Author2

    \vfill

    % Bottom of the page
    {\large \today}

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Ok it's almost what I need, just the "Faculty" text is needed to be in the next line.

Comment: @Dwinar: Fixed my mwe